# Azure API management not sending retry when function app disabled

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-api-management

I've configured an API Management policy to retry to a second region if the first encounters an error.

However, when I disable the primary function app, based in Sydney, there are no retries recorded in Application insights - only the original failing request. There are no function calls recorded in the Melbourne function app.

I've tried a bunch of different configurations. Both region function apps are running fine.

I've got the copied the code below, is there something that I'm missing or not understanding?

Thanks in advance

### API Policy

```xml
<policies>
  <inbound>
    <base />
    <choose>
      <when condition="@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<int>('RetryCounter', 0) == 0)">
        <set-backend-service base-url="{{syndey-function-app}}" />
      </when>
      <otherwise>
        <set-backend-service base-url="{{melbourne-function-app}}" />
      </otherwise>
    </choose>
  </inbound>
  <backend>
    <retry count="1" interval="0" first-fast-retry="true" condition="@(
        context.Response.StatusCode > 400
      )">
      <set-variable name="RetryCounter" value="@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<int>('RetryCounter', 0) + 1)" />
      <forward-request buffer-request-body="true" timeout="15"/>
    </retry>
  </backend>
  <outbound>
    <base />
  </outbound>
  <on-error>
    <base />
  </on-error>
</policies>
```

### 403 Error Response

```html
<h1 id="unavailable">Error 403 - This web app is stopped.</h1>
<p id="tryAgain">
The web app you have attempted to reach is currently stopped and does not 
accept any requests. Please try to reload the page or visit it again soon.
</p>

<p id="toAdmin">
If you are the web app administrator, please find the common 403 error 
scenarios and resolution <a href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2095007" 
target="_blank">here</a>. For further troubleshooting tools and recommendations, 
please visit <a href="https://portal.azure.com/">Azure Portal</a>.
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to replace the single quotes to double quotes because of an error on save:

`context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<int>('RetryCounter', 0)` => `context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<int>("RetryCounter", 0)`

For testing I created two mocked services:

Returns status code 200:
https://rfqapiservicey27itmeb4cf7q.azure-api.net/echo/200/test

Returns status code 403:
https://rfqapiservicey27itmeb4cf7q.azure-api.net/echo/403/test

The `retry` section in the `backend` section will never return to the `inbound` section. So the `choose` condition was only hit at the very beginning.

Therefore, the `choose` condition has to be moved to the `backend` section.

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-backend-service base-url="https://rfqapiservicey27itmeb4cf7q.azure-api.net/echo/403" />
        <!--
            <set-backend-service base-url="{{syndey-function-app}}" />
         -->
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <retry count="1" interval="0" first-fast-retry="true" condition="@(
        context.Response.StatusCode > 400
      )">
            <set-variable name="RetryCounter" value="@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<int>("RetryCounter", 0) + 1)" />
            <choose>
                <when condition="@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<int>("RetryCounter", 0) > 1)">
                    <set-backend-service base-url="https://rfqapiservicey27itmeb4cf7q.azure-api.net/echo/200" />
                    <!--
                        <set-backend-service base-url="{{melbourne-function-app}}" />
                    -->
                </when>
            </choose>
            <forward-request buffer-request-body="true" timeout="15" />
        </retry>
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

[image]

My *sample* operation executes as expected:

https://rfqapiservicey27itmeb4cf7q.azure-api.net/sample/test

[image]

The first hit in the `backend` requests the 403 resource:
[image]

This request is failing, and the `retry` policy sets the *200* in the `backend` section:
[image]

This second request is successful when will return *200* and leave the `backend` section:

[image]

Comment: This is an incredible answer, thank you Markus!

Comment: > Therefore, the choose condition has to be moved to the backend section.

This was the key ingredient. Fantastic understanding and really appreciate your help.